# Permission denied while trying to SSH from gitlab runner to deploy server

Tags: debian, ssh, permissions, alpine-linux, gitlab

I am trying to deploy gitlab repository to my server in gitlab ci pipeline using this pipeline

```
stages:
  - deploy

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  only: 
    - main
  before_script:
    - apk add --update --no-cache openssh
    - install -m 600 -D /dev/null ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | base64 -d > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - ssh-keyscan -H $SSH_HOST > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - echo $SSH_USER
    - echo $SSH_HOST
  script:
    - ssh $SSH_USER@$SSH_HOST "cd $WORK_DIR && git checkout $MAIN_BRANCH && git pull && exit"
  after_script:
    - rm -rf ~/.ssh
```

Variable names hold expected data and I´ve debugged that private key stored in that runner after performing `before_script` looks same as private key on the machine I am trying to connect and all other variables have correct values.

But when I run this pipeline, I am getting these errors while trying to ssh to the deploy server

```
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
SSH_USER@SSH_HOST : Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

(values of user and host are replaced by variable names for better understanding).

Whats weird that I can ssh without password to this server from my computer with no problems.

I should add that OS on docker gitlab runner is `Alpine` and OS on that deploy server is `Debian 11`.

Does anyone knows why my deploy server can not recognize this SSH login with correct private key?

Comment: *private key on the machine I am trying to connect* — the target machine **must never possess** the private key! You only need to add the corresponding public key to the authorized_keys. That said, did you found out what commands generate those two "Permission denied" errors, before the last line generated by the SSH client?